# Best way to include image_tag inside link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, erb

What is the most elegant and readable way to in include (potentially long) `image_tag` calls inside of `link_to`?

Example

```
<%= link_to image_tag('buckminsterfullerene.png', width: '210', height: '60', alt: 'Molecular structure of Buckminsterfullerene'), 'some_long_path.html', title: 'Buckminsterfullerene', rel: 'tooltip', relative: true %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper to keep your views less bloated. For example:

`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```ruby
...
def image_link_to(image_path, url, image_tag_options = { }, link_to_options = { })
  link_to url, link_to_options do
    image_tag image_path, image_tag_options
  end
end
...
```

`app/views/pages/show.html.haml`

```ruby
...
= image_link_to "buckminsterfullerene.png", my_url_helper, { size: '210x60', alt: 'Molecular structure of Buckminsterfullerene' }, { title: 'Buckminsterfullerene', rel: 'tooltip', relative: true }
...
```